# Non convoluted method to add a new line after ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How do you define what's being put after (or between) ng-repeat elements?

Clearly instead of

```
<div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>​
```

I want

```
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>​
```

or

```
<div>
  <div></div>&#10;<div></div>&#10;<div></div>&#10;<div></div>&#10;
</div>​
```

I don't wanna use extra elements. If you are wondering, yes, the div elements are inline-block.

<sub>PS: I removed the comments generated by angular for clarity.</sub>

Comment: Why are your `div`s inline if you want them to be split on their own line?

Comment: @aymericbeaumet The problem at hand is not the type of elements in my example but how to insert something after elegantly.

Comment: Change your CSS class which is making the div's inline

Comment: @Knu: due to the nature of ng-repeat, I don't think it is doable to insert something after each iteration elegantly.

Comment: @aymericbeaumet angular does it (it adds a comment after each element) so yes there must be a way to circumvent the current default behaviour.

Comment: Why do you care about the whitespace format of generated code?

Comment: @EmilLundberg inline elements are sensible to that kind of thing.

Comment: Don't make your divs inline, use spans and you'll be fine. http://jsfiddle.net/temxoqrd/

Comment: @Knu I still don't understand why you would care about (syntactically insignificant) whitespace in code you're not keeping in version control. If you need to inspect the HTML generated by ng-repeat, I recommend using a tool such as Firebug or Chrome dev tools, which display the HTML interactively in a pretty format regardless of whitespace.

Comment: @Emil you are missing the point when you are styling inline elements whitespace do matter and mimicking how angularjs adds comments after each ng-repeat would help in that matter.

Comment: How exactly does it cause problems you can't solve with CSS? A live demo showcasing the problem would be very helpful in understanding your problem.

Comment: @EmilLundberg trust me or check my profile. I know my CSS.

Comment: I'm not questioning your competence, my apologies if it came across that way. I just don't understand what your problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by not use extra element you mean you don't want to do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="test in tests"></div>
     <div></div>&#10
</div>
```

Then you might be willing to do something like this instead (still an extra element, but you're just wrapping the &#10:

```
<div ng-repeat-start="test in tests"></div>
<span ng-repeat-end>&#10</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cwnr8ag5/

Othewise, you'd have to use a directive:

```
<div ng-repeat="test in tests" append="|">test</div>
.directive('append', [function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        append: '@',
    },
    replace: false,
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
        $(elem).after(scope.append);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5gcsscr3/

It would be difficult to do it at compile time... inside an `<ng-repeat>`, the link function is executed after the template has been cloned for that particular element, to do it before... I don't know if it would even work with the way angular repeats.  Might be worth a shot though, I just don't know.

Edit:

It works with 
 if you pass it as a variable instead of as a string:

http://jsfiddle.net/5gcsscr3/3/

Comment: Yeah I meant no extra span in the template. Is there any way to do it at compile time instead?

Comment: Your method is working with "|" but not with "&#10;" on my end. +1 for the effort though.

Comment: If you pass it as a variable it defeats the purpose of using a value for the attribute then.

Comment: You can do it as `append="'&#10;'"` (note the single quotes)

Comment: Ill accept it but I wish someone could investigate how angular adds the comments after each element.